# fullcalendar wrong timespamp for midnight

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.io and I realized that if I create a new event in the month view, dragging across one or more days, it returns a timestamp for the end date which is later rendered as 12 am of the day after while it should be logic that a function date("what-ever-format", timestamp) returns 12 pm of the current day, or, in any case, not the following day.

Any idea how to fix this???

Comment: End dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive** - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object . So yes 12am of the following day is given as the end date, but that time is not considered as being part of the event. The real end time is therefore exactly one millisecond before that. Also "it should be logic that a function date("what-ever-format", timestamp) returns 12 pm of the current day"... 12pm is midday, not midnight.

Comment: ok, sorry for the pm instead of am... Would you trick the insert function by subtracting a millisecond or just leave it as it is and trick the display function in the page where the date is visible? something like if(date = 12:00:00 AM){ print "date-day-before"}

Comment: What insert function are you talking about? And what effect do you expect your "trick" to have? I'm not clear what you're referring to. The question was about the timestamp given to an event when dragging. Not sure where inserting anything comes into that. Also what display are you talking about, if not Fullcalendar itself? Perhaps you can clarify?